How to politely ask not to be first author on a paper?
A few years ago I did a brief undergraduate research apprenticeship in pure math, where I helped a professor come up with a novel construction, and it's in the works to get published. I think I helped come up with the "core idea of the solution", but I was missing many crucial details and the formalism necessary for publication-ready research. I left before I could help flesh these out.
Since then, a lot more work has been done on the paper to resolve more complex issues than the ones I had initially worked on. Perhaps my "core idea" is still there, but as far as I can tell upwards of 75% of the words aren't my own, if I had to give some quantitative metric of my actual contribution. I've switched pursuits, I'm no longer in pure math or in academia really, and I don't have the time nor the wherewithal really to continue contributing meaningfully to the paper. Since I left I believe most of the substantial additions and revisions have been made by my academic advisor and another grad student.
Nonetheless, my academic advisor wants to keep me as first author. He doesn't expect me to continue working on it, he understands that my situation doesn't really allow me to keep contributing. I've already expressed my concern once that it'd be "unfair" to make me first author, but he insisted that my contribution was larger than I give myself credit for.
However, this was before I received an update from him a few weeks ago that there were some larger issues with the proof (which him and the grad student formalized) which they would have to address. As more work is done on the paper - work I'm not involved in - I wonder if there's a threshold beyond which I would no longer be considered the primary contributor.
I can't help but feel like it's a bit of "stolen valour" - I always imagined that a first author should be deeply entrenched in the material of the paper, and I certainly don't feel that way anymore. Moreover I worry that I wouldn't be able to adequately answer any future questions on the material if I get reached out to by another researcher.
Should I ask, a second time, not to be made first author? If so, how can I go about doing it politely? Or is my understanding incorrect and this is a perfectly typical scenario in which to be made first author?

In mathematics, it is a standard practice to follow alphabetical orders of authors' surnames.

In your particular case, I would assume that the author order is alphabetical. With a name like "Ala", a mathematician will find themselves listed first very frequently.
If this wasn't the case, my recommendation would have been to offer once more giving up the first authorship. If the supervisor still thinks you should be it, go along with it and feel good about it. They are more experienced, and it is reasonable to defer to their judgement.
Regarding some details: First, the number of words you recognize as your own is not a suitable meaure of contribution. Heavily editing a draft by an undergad can easily mean rewriting every single word while still all the novel insight comes from the student.
Second, in maths there is a very widespread sentiment than when it comes to the distribution of credit, we ought to be very generous with junior folks. The idea of taking away a first-authorship (if that happens to be a thing) from an undergrad feels icky to me. In the situation of your supervisor, I could easily imagine suggesting the honour should go to the other grad student, but definitely not to me.
Finally, don't worry about potential future questions about the paper. Regardless of the author order, it is always reasonable to share such questions with your coauthors and try to come up with a response together. Also, there is often a separate "corresponding author" role anyway.

If first author is simply due to alphabetical order, surely the professor would have said that when Michael raised his concerns?

In mathematics, authors are almost always listed alphabetically.  The philosophical assumption here is that if someone is listed as an author of a paper, then they have made a significant intellectual contribution to the paper, roughly equal to the intellectual contributions of the other authors.  There is really no such thing as "first author" in mathematics (for the most part—I am sure that there are some exceptions, but they are likely rare).
This an important part of the culture of mathematical research, and is different enough from other fields that the American Mathematical Society has issued a cultural statement on author order, the core of which reads

In most areas of mathematics, joint research is a sharing of ideas and skills that cannot be
attributed to the individuals separately. The roles of researchers are seldom differentiated (in the
way they are in laboratory sciences, for example). Determining which person contributed which
ideas is often meaningless because the ideas grow from complex discussions among all partners.
Naming a "senior" researcher may indicate the relative status of the participants, but its purpose
is not to indicate the relative merit of the contributions. Joint work in mathematics almost
always involves a small number of researchers contributing equally to a research project.
For this reason, mathematicians traditionally list authors on joint papers in alphabetical order.
An analysis of journal articles with at least one U.S. based author shows that nearly half were
jointly authored. Of these, more than 75% listed the authors in alphabetical order. In pure
mathematics, nearly all joint papers (over 90%) list authors alphabetically.


As Arno notes in a comment, pure math authors are normally listed alphabetically and contributions noted, perhaps, in an acknowledgements paragraph or section.
But, let me add also, that in pure math, a key idea for a problem or a solution might come from someone in a five minute conversation over coffee. In other fields that would be considered grounds for "first" authorship since, without that insight and contribution, no progress would be made.
I've been a minor "author" on a CS paper in which all of the writing was done by another minor author, just because he was the best writer in the group. But the drivers of the project and all of the key ideas came from two others who were "firsts”
Also, in theoretical aspects CS, many of us prefer alphabetical listings of authors. In some fields, supervisors may wish to be authors even with minimal contribution. But in math and CS (theory, at least) that seems less common. I was not an "author" on any of my doctoral students work (CS), nor was my own advisor an "author" on my dissertation.
I'd guess that in nearly every ethical system you have qualified for first authorship, even given that you didn't put the words to paper yourself. It is about ideas and insight, not the specific words.

I wasn't aware of the tradition in mathematics to list authors alphabetically (as opposed to listing in order of importance of their contribution). I'm entering this answer anyway (1) to give a different perspective; and (2) in case someone comes to this question in the future from a non-mathematical field.
Plus the answer is short: Take a cue from child-rearing or even military custom. Don't just tell people what they should not do. Instead, give them "positive instructions": Tell them what you would like them to do instead of the undesired behavior.
To put this in context, saying "I don't want to be first author" isn't that helpful because it creates a emptiness in the expectations that others have already mentally committed to. Instead, decide who you think the first author should be. List the reasons why. Then make a propsal: "I think so-and-so should be first author instead of me because..." and then list the reasons.
Having a proposal to consider gives the other authors something concrete to critique. It also sort of puts them on the defense: They would feel the need to justify their response, and if your proposal is fact-based and rational, that would be harder for them to do. Saying that you don't want to be first author can feel negative and prime the other authors to disagree.  Proposing an alternative feels more positive and does some of the mental work for the others, allowing them to just agree or not, without having to work out alternatives for themselves.
